# Find and replace in C

Tags: c, file

The program is supposed to read data from `stdin` to a text file, and then perform a find and replace on the file, with the condition that the new word is longer  than the old one. It compiles fine without any errors or warnings, but the issue is that `fread` is not working, it seems to return a 0 so the while loop isn't starting. The print file function is just there to be able to check the contents of the file, it's not part of the final code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000
#define OLD_WORD_SIZE 24
#define NEW_WORD_SIZE 64

void write_to_file(const char *s);
void replace_word(const char *s, const char *old, const char *new);
void print_file(const char *s);

int main(void){
    const char file_name[] = "text.txt";
    int c;
    char old_word[OLD_WORD_SIZE];
    char new_word[NEW_WORD_SIZE];
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        switch(c){
        case 'w':
            getchar();
            write_to_file(file_name);
            break;
        case 'r':
            getchar();
            puts("Enter the word you want to replace");
            fgets(old_word, sizeof(old_word), stdin);
            old_word[strlen(old_word) - 1] = '\0';
            puts("Enter the new word");
            fgets(new_word, sizeof(new_word), stdin);
            new_word[strlen(new_word) - 1]  = '\0';
            if(strlen(old_word) >= strlen(new_word)){
                printf("Error: can't replace \"%s\" with \"%s\":\n\"%s\" is too small\n", old_word, new_word, new_word);
                break;
            }
            replace_word(file_name, old_word, new_word);
            getchar();
            break;
        case 'p':
            print_file(file_name);
            getchar();
            getchar();
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid command:%i\n", c);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void write_to_file(const char *s){
    FILE *out_file;
    if((out_file = fopen(s, "w")) == NULL){
        perror(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        fputc(c, out_file);
    }
    fclose(out_file);
}

void print_file(const char *s){
    FILE *in_file;
    if((in_file = fopen(s, "r")) == NULL){
        perror(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(in_file)) != EOF){
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    fclose(in_file);
}

void replace_word(const char *s, const char *old_word, const char *new_word){
    char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    FILE *original_file;
    FILE *copy;

    if((original_file = fopen(s, "r")) == NULL){
        perror(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((copy = fopen("copy.txt", "w")) == NULL){
        perror("text");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int old_word_len = strlen(old_word);
    int new_word_len = strlen(new_word);

    char *src;
    char *dst;
    char *tmp;
    while(fread(&buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 1, original_file) == 1){
        if((tmp = strstr(buffer, old_word))){
            buffer = realloc(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE + new_word_len - old_word_len + 1);
            src = tmp + old_word_len;
            dst = tmp + new_word_len;
            memmove(dst, src, BUFFER_SIZE - strlen(src));
            memcpy(tmp, new_word, new_word_len);
            fwrite(&buffer, BUFFER_SIZE + new_word_len - old_word_len + 1, 1, copy);
        }
        else{
            fwrite(&buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 1, copy);
        }
        fseek(original_file, -old_word_len, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
```

The code is incomplete, it's only missing a small segment, I don't move the modified version back to the original file.

Why is `fread` returning a zero? Are there any other mistakes in the code?

I realise I should free buffer at the end.

Comment: Don't use `fread` on a text file. Read line by line with `fgets`. Otherwise the `fread` might  break a word you want to detect.

Comment: @WeatherVane `fgets` wouldn't work here because it'll stop on the first '\n`. I need to read a specific number of bytes.

Comment: You try to read 1 item of size BUFFER_SIZE, you perhaps want `fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, original_file)`, i.e. read (at most) BUFFER_SIZE items of size 1.

Comment: So your word search spans two text lines? As in `"fi\nnd"`

Comment: Why `fseek(original_file, -9, SEEK_CUR);`?  What is that supposed to do?

Comment: @WEatherVane I suppose so, the buffer is only 1000 bytes long, if a line is theoretically longer than that, then the word I'm looking for can be split.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it's supposed to be `fseek(original_file, -old_word_len, SEEK_CUR);` It's to make sure I don't read only parts of the word I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to swap the second and third arguments to [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html).

The way you have it, it will only return `1` if it can read `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes.

```
 n = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, original_file);
 if (n == BUFFER_SIZE) /* buffer full, needs to read more */;
 if (n > 0) /* read n bytes */;
```

*Even better as suggested in comments is to use `fgets()`.*

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `&buffer` there. Since buffer already is a char pointer, pass `buffer` as a first argument to fread and fwrite.

Comment: I tried that but it still returns 0.

Comment: Then start looking at errno, strerror and/or perror.